# jQuery and iOS devices

Tags: jquery, ios, browser

I have plain text in html format. I add classes to certain tags to format them on the fly using jQuery.

Everything will work fine on PC and Android, but nothing happens on iOS. What could be the mistake?

Sample code is below

```
<script>
var $=jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function() { 
    var dialog = $( "p:has(strong)" ).addClass( "wi-dialog" );
    var chapter = $( "p:has(ins)" ).addClass( "wi-chapter" );
    dialog.html(function(i, v) { return v.replace(/(?<=\n)\s*(\(.*?\)).*?/g, '<span class="wi-remark">$&</span>') });

    var more = $(".wi-remark:contains(MORE)").addClass( "wi-more").removeClass( "wi-remark");

    var p = $('p:not(.wi-dialog,.wi-chapter)');
    p.filter(function() { 
        return ((/^[0-9.]+$/).test($(this).html())); 
    }).addClass("wi-number");
    p.filter(function() {
        return ((/^(THE END)+$/).test($(this).html())); }).addClass( "wi-end" );
    });
});
</script>
```

the problem is here

```
dialog.html(function(i, v) { return v.replace(/(?<=\n)\s*(\(.*?\)).*?/g, '<span class="wi-remark">$&</span>') });
```

text example

```
<p><strong>HENRY</strong>
Gather more wood.</p>

<p>Fitzgerald waits for Henry to turn, then gives his back an exaggerated salute.</p>

<p><strong>FITZGERALD</strong><br>
(under his breath)<br>
Shame my Pap was a broken down drunk. Else he could’ve bought me a Captain’s job too.</p>

<p>Boone snickers. Fitzgerald stomps his boot onto a branch, easily snaps it into two easy-to-carry pieces.</p>

<p><strong>FITZGERALD</strong> (CONT’D)<br>
We got a plan for these fires, Captain, or are we roastin’ berries all the way up to Fort Union?</p>

<p><strong>HENRY</strong><br>
Glass and the others will be back with some game, Fitzgerald. Just make sure you have the fires ready.</p>

<p><strong>FITZGERALD</strong><br>
My supper’s in the hands of a injun- lover, a peach-fuzz kid and a half- wit dummy. Hell, my belly feels full already.</p>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should work for you. The problem was the negative lookbehind, which doesn't work on some iOS versions. Now it's using a non-capturing group instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dialog = $( "p:has(strong)" ).addClass( "wi-dialog" )
  for (var i = 0; i < dialog.length; i++) {
    e = dialog.eq(i)
    var e_html = e.html()
    var pattern = /(?:\n)\s*(\(.*?\)).*?/gm
    var match = pattern.exec(e_html)
    while (match != null) {
      e_html = e_html.replace(match[1], '<span class="wi-remark">$&</span>')
      match = pattern.exec(e_html)
    }
    e.html(e_html)
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <strong>FITZGERALD</strong> (CONT’D)<br>
      Shut up, boy, you don’t get no say in this.<br>
      (back to Henry)<br>
      And in case you hadn’t noticed, Captain, we’re seventeen men short of what we were.
      (off the wounded trapper)<br>
      Eighteen before long.
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>FITZGERALD</strong><br>
      (under his breath)<br>
      Shame my Pap was a broken down drunk. Else he could’ve bought me a Captain’s job too.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works but with only one paragraph. if there are a lot of heroes and many dialogues? Try adding a few paragraphs with different names.

Comment: Can you post your text

Comment: @AndreyShandrov It's finished, try again now

Comment: @AndreyShandrov What is hard?

Comment: @AndreyShandrov That's great. If you like it please upvote as well

Comment: I found an easier way `dialog.html(function(i, v) { return v.replace(/(?:\n)\s*(\(.*?\)).*?/g, '<span class="wi-remark">$&</span>') });`